# UIPageViewController Affecting UIImage color?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

**What I'm Doing**: I am creating a custom view controller for encouraging users to invite friends to the app in exchange for premium features. I am doing this via presenting a `UIViewController` that has a container view with a `UIPageViewController` embedded within the container view. The details of all of the premium features are displayed in the embedded `UIPageViewController`'s view controllers. I have an image of some bubbles that match our brand colors that are on the leading or trailing edge of each of the `UIPageViewController`'s view controllers such that the images "connect" into one image when panning between each view controller. This is what it looks like:

[image]

**My problem**: The problem with this approach is that, when half way panned between two of the `UIPageViewController`'s view controllers, the colors of the bubbles in between the respective view controllers **do not match**:

[image]

Notice that the shades of blue where the images meet up between each respective view controller **are not the same shade.**

This is despite using the same "bubbles" image for each view controller, which looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**
I've decided to go ahead and create a cocoapod that does the same thing presented in the question above. [Feel free to check it out!](https://github.com/ChopinDavid/UpsellViewController)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have a few pages to show, abandon UIPageViewController and configure the entire sliding interface as the content of one big continuous paged UIScrollView instead. As a bonus you won’t have to work out the splitting of the bubble image.

Comment: Are page view controllers only preferable when you need the content to be view controllers, rather than subviews? I’m just curious what a good rule of thumb is to use one over the other.

Comment: Yes and when there are many pages. I have a flashcard app with 1000 pages. You can’t load them all at once; you’d run out of memory. So I had to invent my own page view controller! Naturally when UIPageViewController came along I adopted it instantly. But for half a dozen pages, you won’t have a memory issue, and your single sliding interface was never fitted to a UIPageViewController in the first place.

Comment: Now that I’ve already got the above interface in place, is there any reason I’d want to switch to the scroll view other than the image color issue?

Comment: Also, I may bounty this just because it might be useful for everybody to know **why** the page view controller would cause this behavior, and if there’s anything that could fix the issue for people who have to use a page view controller rather than a scroll view.

Comment: Well, UIPageViewController was never meant for a continuous sliding sheet in the first place. Pages are expected to be separate. I’m impressed you got it to behave this way at all.

Comment: Although I'm sad to see my embedded `UIPageViewController` contraption go, the page enabled scroll view worked perfectly. I may make a cocoapod or something for this sort of thing if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Yay!!! I notice you didn't ask me how to coordinate the UIPageControl with the paged scroll view, so I presume you worked that out as well.

Comment: Yep, looking at the documentation, it’s essentially the same I just had to set page enabled to true and make sure the scroll view’s content width was a multiple of the scroll view’s bounds width. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, so you were not using the UIPageViewController's built-in page control. That must have made things easier.

Comment: I went ahead and created a cocoapod framework for based off your recommendations. Its the first one I made, but figured you might be interested! https://github.com/ChopinDavid/UpsellViewController